# Laravel Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\ProfilesController::index() must be an instance of App\User, string given

Tags: laravel, controller

I have a problem with my Laravel site. Basically I tried adding language switches to my Instagram clone and it showed this problem while logged in and tried go to my profile site

This is the code to the controller where it shows the problem:

```
public function index(User $user)
    {
        $user = User::find($user);
        $follows = (auth()->user()) ? auth()->user()->following->contains($user->id) : false;
    // Caching Post count
    $postCount = Cache::remember(
        'count.posts.' . $user->id,
        now()->addSeconds(30),
        function () use ($user) {
            return $user->posts->count();
        });
    // Caching Followers count
    $followersCount = Cache::remember(
        'count.followers' . $user->id,
        now()->addSeconds(30),
        function () use ($user) {
            return $user->profile->followers->count();
        });
    // Caching Following count
    $followingCount = Cache::remember(
        'count.following' . $user->id,
        now()->addSeconds(30),
        function () use ($user) {
            return $user->following->count();
        });

    return view('profiles.index', compact('user' , 'follows',  'postCount', 'followersCount', 'followingCount'));

    //return view('profiles.index', compact('user' , 'follows'));
}
```

If someone's interested in the project that I created, I followed this video:

https://youtu.be/ImtZ5yENzgE

Comment: remove the User $user from the `public function index(User $user)` to `public function index()`

Comment: Change `public function index(User $user) ` to `public function index(Request $request, $user) `

Comment: changed to public function index(Request $request, $user) and it shows that Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Comment: No need to use `User $user` as argument.

Comment: if i dont use User $user in the argument it shows the error of not knowing the id